# How to have a class in another class by a different name?

Tags: java, class

I have a class called `Playership` and another class called `Game`. I wanna have `Playership` class in `Game` class by the name of player. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: This is quite a **beginning** question, please learn these basics first from [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2979739/learn-java/java-101-classes-and-objects-in-java.html), or [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classes-objects-java/) or [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/constructors-in-java/).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is something like this:

```
class Playership {
    public Playership() {
        System.out.println("This is a playership, please be careful!");
    }
}

class Game {
    private Playership playership;
    public Game() {
        System.out.println("Starting the game...");
        this.playership = new Playership();
        System.out.println("I have a playership now.");
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Game game = new Game();

        System.out.println("The end of the Game");
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
Starting the game...
This is a playership, please be careful!
I have a playership now.
The end of the Game
```